# Check for isNewUser with Firebase email link auth using modular JS SDK

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

The [official snippet here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth?authuser=1#completing_sign-in_in_a_web_page) says:

```
  // You can access the new user via result.user
  // Additional user info profile not available via:
  // result.additionalUserInfo.profile == null
  // You can check if the user is new or existing:
  // result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser
```

Even the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo) says :

> Object that contains additional user information as a result of a
> successful sign-in, link, or re-authentication operation.

However I get `additionalUserInfo is undefined`. I need to detect if the email link login is a new user or not.

My code:

```
await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
const result = await signInWithEmailLink(auth, email.value, window.location.href);
if (result && result.user) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('email');
    window.localStorage.removeItem('its');
    console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser()); // undefined
    return router.push({ path: "/dashboard" }); 
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code where `additionalUserInfo` undefined?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Sure, done.

Comment: Tried both, its the `additionalUserInfo` thats undefined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `getAdditionalUserInfo` method separately in the new modular SDK as mentioned in this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5257#issuecomment-895319041).

```js
import {signInWithEmailLink, getAdditionalUserInfo} from "firebase/auth"

const result = await signInWithEmailLink(auth, email.value, window.location.href);
const {isNewUser} = getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
// Pass the UserCredential                ^^^^^^
```

Comment: I just created a [PR](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/pull/220) for the same. The documentation should get updated with this if PR is merged.