# FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/user-token-expired)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created a new form after creating a user with phone number authentication(in firebase), But an error keeps on coming after submitting  FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/user-token-expired)
The Error is Comming in this code

```
//This Component is used to store the Name ,Phone Number Of new User  Which have Registered in SignUp With Number
import "./Auth.scss";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { updateProfile, updateEmail } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../../firebase/config";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router";
import usePhoneSignUp from "../../hooks/usePhoneSignUp";
import { update } from "lodash";

const SaveUserDetails = () => {
  //code to extract userType after navigating from SignUpWithNumber page
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const userType = state.userType;
  console.log(userType);

  // .......
  const {
    signUp,
    error: signupError,
    isPending: signupIsPending,
  } = usePhoneSignUp();

  const [name, setname] = useState();
  const [email, setemail] = useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    switch (name) {
      case "displayname":
        setname(value);
        break;
      case "email":
        setemail(value);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
  const updateEmailUser = () => {
    updateEmail(auth.currentUser, email)
      .then(() => {
        // Email updated!
        // ...
        console.log("email Updated");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // An error occurred
        console.log("email Updated");

        // ...
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  const updateUserProfile = () => {
    updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
      displayName: name,
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("profile Updated" + name + " " + email);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error + "In update profile");
      });
    updateEmailUser();
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    // updateEmailUser();
    updateUserProfile();
    signUp(name, userType, email);
    let path =
      userType === "salonOwner" ? "/addBuisnessDetails" : "/salonsNearby";
    if (signupError) {
      console.log(signupError.message);
    }
    return navigate(path, { replace: true });
  };

  //query function for saloon

  return (
    <>
      <div className="form-wrapper ">
        <div id="register-form">
          <p className="login-title register-title">Complete Your Profile</p>
          <div className="login-hr" />

          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group login-sj">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputName1">Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputName1"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Your Name"
                name="displayname"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group login-sj">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputEmail2"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                name="email"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            {/* <div className="form-group login-sj">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1"></label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleInputPassword2"
              placeholder="Password"
              value={userPassword}
              onChange={(e) => setUserPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div> */}
            {signupIsPending ? (
              <>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn-auth-sj btn btn-primary"
                  disabled
                >
                  Save Details
                </button>
              </>
            ) : (
              <>
                <button type="submit" className="btn-auth-sj btn btn-primary">
                  Save Details
                </button>
              </>
            )}
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SaveUserDetails;
```

The part where error is Comming

```
.catch((error) => {
        console.log(error + "In update profile");
      });
```

Due to this my displayName Is not getting saved and after submitting user is getting logged out automatically.
I also asked this question previously and implemented it as answered [Is their any function signupwithphonenumber in firebase just like signupwithemailandpassword? (for web) I want to make user register with his creds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72735490/is-their-any-function-signupwithphonenumber-in-firebase-just-like-signupwithemai)
Thanks In advance

Comment: Which function here throws the error? Can you also share what the `signUp()` function is from `usePhoneSignUp` ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj  In updateUserProfile the Catch block is throwing error.And in SignUp() function we are just storing more user data by creating a collection named users which get stored in firestoredatabase( by more user data I mean user-type which is related to my project).

Comment: @Dharmaraj you can just ignore the signup function its has nothing to do with error.

Comment: Ok here's the twist the session was getting expired because we were spam testing .

Comment: After waiting for some time it got automatically resolved idk how .

Comment: Oh okay, you have two Solutions to avoid this spam testing. One, use test phone numbers from Firebase console. Two, use Firebase emulator. I prefer Firebase emulator because it creates a six digit code for you in the logs and you can emulate all services. Post the answer to your question to help others in future because your code is working.

Comment: turns out i was wrong before related to session, there is still the same issue and it is arising when I am updating user displayName in firebase auth . This time the error is occurring from the beginning  . @Dharmaraj

Comment: Can you try `auth.currentUser.reload().then(() => { /* update profile function here */ })` in the `updateUserProfile` function?

Comment: @Dharmaraj It's working fine now no error ,let me test some more time

Answer (score 1):

Okay So the problem got resolved gust by wrapping  updateProfile function(one provided by firebase) into

```
auth.currentUser.reload().then(() => { /* update profile function here */ })
```

Or In my case :-

```
 const updateUserProfile = () => {
    auth.currentUser.reload().then(() => {
      updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
        displayName: name,
      })
        .then(() => {
          console.log("profile Updated" + name + " " + email);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error + "In update profile");
        });
      updateEmailUser();
    });
  };
```