# Is there a way to only sign in registered users in Firebase Phone Authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a React app with Firebase Back End that requires the user to register and sign in using their phone number. The problem is that currently, even for a user that does not have an account, once they receive the OTP, they are automatically registered. Is there a way to check if the user is not registered and instead ask them to register rather than sign them in?

My sign in function

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(phone != ''){
        setExpanded(true);
        generateRecaptcha();
        let appVerifier = window.recaptureVerifier;
        signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phone, appVerifier)
        .then(confirmationResult => {
            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        
    }
}
```

OTP verification:

```
const verifyOTP = (e) => {
     let otp = e.target.value;
     setOtp(otp);
     if(otp.length === 6) {
        console.log(otp);
        let confirmationResult = window.confirmationResult;
        confirmationResult.confirm(otp).then((result) => {
            const user = result.user;
            if(user != null){
                console.log('Loged');
                router.push('/home')
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
          
     }
}
```

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: I have provided an answer below to your question. please check

Answer (score 1):

[SignInWithPhoneNumber](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signInWithPhoneNumber) method will automatically sign up a new user if the user doesn't exist. There is no way to prevent users from signing up,you can check if the returned user is a new user and if it's new, delete and sign out the user manually.

check the isNewUser property after authentication to check if user logged in for the first time or not.you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72735589/18265638)

```
x.confirm(code)
  .then((result) => {
    // User signed in successfully.
    const { isNewUser } = getAdditionalUserInfo(result)
    
    if (isNewUser) {
      // New user - sign up
    } else {
      // Existing user - log in
    }
  })
```

However, you can disable new user sign up with email providers by setting the flag `disableSignUp.status` to `true`. This will display an error message when new users attempt to sign up.You can refer this [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configure-email-provider) for more information

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Sathi's answer:

You can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) in [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to check if a user exists in Firebase Authentication with the given phone number. An example of such a Cloud Function in Python:

```py
@https_fn.on_call()
def phone_number_registered(req: https_fn.CallableRequest):
    phone_number = req.data['phone_number']

    try:
        auth.get_user_by_phone_number(phone_number)
        return {'registered': True}
    except:
        return {'registered': False}
```

In your frontend, you can then call this Cloud Function when a user enters a phone number to check if the user is already registered in Firebase Authentication. If this is the case, you can call the `signInWithPhoneNumber` function. Otherwise, you reject.